# How to troubleshoot ASK ChangeReport failing with INVALID_REQUEST_EXCEPTION

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Summary: I am getting an INVALID_REQUEST_EXCEPTION response when attempting to submit a ChangeReport event.

I'm troubleshooting with postman.
POSTing to: https://api.amazonalexa.com/v3/events
One header: Authorization with my token (if this is wrong, I get the correct error)

My body:

```
{
    "event":{
        "header":{
            "messageId":"06a6278a-0c38-47e5-90e9-12eef0205487",
            "namespace":"Alexa",
            "name":"ChangeReport",
            "payloadVersion":"3"
        },
        "endpoint":{
            "scope":{
                "type":"BearerToken",
                "token":"XXX My Token XXX"
            },
            "endpointId":"BedroomLight"
        },
        "payload":{
            "change": {
                "cause" : {
                    "type" : "PHYSICAL_INTERACTION"
                },
                "properties":[
                {
                    "namespace": "Alexa.PowerController",
                    "name": "powerState",
                    "value": "ON",
                    "timeOfSample": "2019-03-09T15:22:48Z",
                    "uncertaintyInMilliseconds": 500
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The response:

```
{
    "header": {
        "namespace": "System",
        "name": "Exception",
        "messageId": "bb7a3bb7-5c2c-4568-8a31-ae24a075f15e"
    },
    "payload": {
        "code": "INVALID_REQUEST_EXCEPTION",
        "description": "The request was malformed."
    }
}
```

My input passes the schema validation.

I've tried substituting known invalid values to see if I could shift the error message and narrow down the root cause.

I compared to other code examples in Github and I'm not seeing an obvious error.

I'm not sure how to narrow the problem scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contrary to my understanding above, I was not using the correct BearerToken. I was using the original OAuth code provided in the grant response (I didn't understand the LoginWithAmazon/LWA portion of the security exchange).

The further mistake that made this difficult was the lack of a security error.  When I created the Authorization header, I left out the type (Bearer) and just had my value in the value area of the header, which might have been the base reason for the format error.